# How are tabs treated differently in different systems?

Tags: process, tabs

> To maintain portability, tab
>   characters must not be used in
>   indentation, since different systems
>   treat tabs differently.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Did you see this question. It may have the answer you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265915

Comment: That answer didn't answer my questions

Comment: To successfully answer this question, we need some context. Where did your quote come from?

Comment: I came here from the YAML spec as well. In all my years coding, I've never heard that systems treat tab characters differently and therefore they aren't as portable as space characters. I'd love some insight into this YAML requirement on indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Where is this quote from? Does it talk about indentation in code, or in WYSIWYG documents, or in output of console programs that must be parsable?

As for code indentation, tabs can have same size as any number of spaces (usually 2, 4 or 8). So if you mix spaces and tabs, once you open same file in different editor with different tab settings you would see broken indentation. The solution to that is not to use spaces for indentation (opposite of what your quote says).

Another advantage of all-tabs indentation is ability to adjust visual size of tabs (some people like 'em bigger).

Python has this insane whitespace scoping mechanism that would cause inconsistent indentation to break code.

Comment: Ok, data definition then. My answer doesn't apply and I'm not quite sure what is understood as "system" in this case, so disregard this :).